# Java get id of textView or Button by click with android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, button, textview, click

I want to get a textview or button ID if I click on it without setting a pre-click event. How can I do this?

For example:

**User clicks on textview**

than:

**Receives R.id.textview3**

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop and increment the id and set it TextView

Answer (score 0):

id is a integer type you can store it as a variable

```
int id = R.id.textview3;
textview.setOnClickListner{
    //use id variable here for example
    fun(id);
}
```